# get a Range by using getR(2,"firstname")

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to address the cells via the headline name.
for example. **getR(sheet, 2,"firstname")**

### example data:

1: firstname, lastname
2: john, berg
3: mark, tost

### I expect the following:

getR(sheet, 2,"firstname")
should then give me :
**sheet.getRange(2, 1)**

Maybe there is a possibility to make it write:
**sheet.getR(2,"firstname")** ?

I see the following advantages:
it is easier to understand and if the layout of the headings is reversed, it still works.

### my prototype:

```
function getR(sheet, name) { // https://gist.github.com/printminion/5520691

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheet);
    var range = ss.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss.getMaxColumns()).getValues()[0]; 
    Logger.log(range);
    for (var row in range) {
        Logger.log(range[row ]);
        if ( range[row ] == name ) {
            return parseInt(row ) + 1;
        }
    }
    throw 'failed';
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to represent `2`in `getR(sheet, 2,"firstname")` what is the desired return result. An index? a string?

Comment: Ok. What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getR(row,sheet,headername){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var nA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<nA.length;i++){
    if(i+1==row){
      for(var j=0;j<nA[i].length;j++){
        if(nA[0][j]==headername){
          return nA[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  throw 'failed';
}
```

Comment: works. i get the first entry in column **firstname** with: var range = **getR(2,'Addresses','firstname')**; 
Browser.msgBox(range);